# What does scriptures say about dealing with family conflicts from an Advaitic point of view?

Tags: advaita, life

We do not have control over the family that we are born in.

But by gods grace, past Karma, etc. if an individual is somehow able to develop deeper understanding about his true self.

Then how would you deal with issues, conflicts, misunderstandings that may arise in the family.

Does one just not participate/intervene at all?

Comment: @UdayKrishna Dont delete your comments. They are so valuable

Comment: @UdayKrishna welcome but dont delete comments!

Comment: I don't think such a person would intervene, rather he would remain aloof from such family matters, since he has tasted the supreme and has no need to dwell in worldly matters ... OR maybe once in a while he would give advice to people who are suffering, just like sages do ... OR if the person is too compassionate and has attained some psychic (siddhai) powers during his self realization then he can even use them to heal others.

Comment: This type of advice is not the purport of the Upanishads or Advaita. Their purport is Brahman. The smritis deal with this.

Comment: Here "according to Advaitic point of view" doens't look much meaningful.

Comment: @pandya. Haha. Yes I thought about that when writing this question. But just wanted to make a point that if someone who follows Advaitic teachings but is still in Samsara and not yet taken Sannyasa then how would he deal with worldly things and problems? Does he not participate at all